Parameter identification in multinomial logit
I am estimating $\beta$ the following model:
$$
p_1=\frac{\exp(\beta x_1)}{\exp(\beta x_1)+\exp(\beta x_2) + \exp(\beta x_3)}
$$
$$
p_2=\frac{\exp(\beta x_2)}{\exp(\beta x_1)+\exp(\beta x_2) + \exp(\beta x_3)}
$$
$$
p_3=\frac{\exp(\beta x_3)}{\exp(\beta x_1)+\exp(\beta x_2) + \exp(\beta x_3)}
$$
Is $\beta$ identified in this model?
If not, to identify $\beta$, do I need to normalize a choice to 1? For example:
$$
p_1=\frac{1}{1+\exp(\beta x_2) + \exp(\beta x_3)}
$$
$$
p_2=\frac{\exp(\beta x_2)}{1+\exp(\beta x_2) + \exp(\beta x_3)}
$$
$$
p_3=\frac{\exp(\beta x_3)}{1+\exp(\beta x_2) + \exp(\beta x_3)}
$$
If $\beta$ is identified in the first model, are $\beta$s in the two models measuring different things?
